# Complex number equation solving

Tags: complex-numbers

Can somebody help me to solve this equation?

$$(\frac{iz}{2+i})^3=-8$$ ?
I'm translating this into

$(\frac{iz}{2+i})=-2$

But i recon it's wrong ...

Comment: Of course 2 + i , sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine the solutions  $w_1,w_2,w_3$ of the equation $w^3=-8$.

Then solve  $\frac{iz}{2+i}=w_j $ for j=1,2,3

Comment: Ahh, I think i know what are you talking about, I will try now

Comment: I've got correct answers, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right way 
$$\frac { iz }{ 2+i } =\sqrt [ 3 ]{ 8\cdot \left( -1 \right)  } =-2\left( \cos { \frac { k\pi  }{ 3 } +i\sin { \frac { k\pi  }{ 3 }  }  }  \right) ,k=0,1,2$$  check for instance  $k=0$

$$\frac { iz }{ 2+i } =-2\\ iz=-4-2i\\ z=\frac { -4-2i }{ i } =\frac { -4i+2 }{ { i }^{ 2 } } =-2+4i$$

Comment: I'm little bit confused. In your equation we will get maxium 1 answer, while in my script I will need 3

Comment: Yes. This answer is missing two on the three answer. You need to run the same argument for the three roots on $-8$.

Comment: I've checked, your answer is correct but there is still missing two of them

Comment: I dont understand, can u write it for me step by step?

Comment: Sure: write $-8=|8|e^{i\pi}$. Then you can find three complex numbers satsfying $z^3=-8$, given by : $2e^{i\pi/3}=1+\sqrt{3} i,e^{i\pi/3+i2\pi/3}=2e^{i\pi}=-2, 2e^{i\pi/3+i4\pi/3}=2e^{i5\pi/3}=1-\sqrt{3} i$